# How do you select a sprite image from a sprite sheet in Python?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to import a sprite sheet and select one sprite. How would I do this in Python/pygame?

Comment: You should provide more information, like what libraries and frameworks you are using for game development. The solution will likely depend on that.

Comment: oh. Yes, I forgot to mention I am using Pygame.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made this, it might interest you:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

SCREEN_X=400
SCREEN_Y=400
#Screen size

SPRT_RECT_X=0  
SPRT_RECT_Y=0
#This is where the sprite is found on the sheet

LEN_SPRT_X=100
LEN_SPRT_Y=100
#This is the length of the sprite

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_X, SCREEN_Y)) #Create the screen
sheet = pygame.image.load('C:\YOURFILE') #Load the sheet

sheet.set_clip(pygame.Rect(SPRT_RECT_X, SPRT_RECT_Y, LEN_SPRT_X, LEN_SPRT_Y)) #Locate the sprite you want
draw_me = sheet.subsurface(sheet.get_clip()) #Extract the sprite you want

backdrop = pygame.Rect(0, 0, SCREEN_X, SCREEN_Y) #Create the whole screen so you can draw on it

screen.blit(draw_me,backdrop) #'Blit' on the backdrop
pygame.display.flip()
#Draw the sprite on the screen
```

Hope I could help

Comment: I realize this is resurrection a pretty old answer, but I was wondering why you went to the trouble of using set_clip and get_clip when you could have just passed the Rect you wanted to subsurface directly.

Comment: Oh wow, this was from almost a year ago lol.  Well, back then I was actually still new to pygame even though I was answering questions, and that was just how I learned it.  It also seems a bit cleaner to me the way it is.  But you are correct, you could just as easily pass the Rect itself.

Answer (score 7):

The above spritesheet loader is a good method. Based on that code, I made this generalized function that works for any spritesheet:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
# Sprite Sheet Loader - hammythepig
#
# Edited by Peter Kennedy
#
# License - Attribution - hammythepig
    #http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560446/how-do-you-select-a-sprite-image-from-a-sprite-sheet-in-python
#
# Version = '2.0'

import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *

def sprite_sheet(size,file,pos=(0,0)):

    #Initial Values
    len_sprt_x,len_sprt_y = size #sprite size
    sprt_rect_x,sprt_rect_y = pos #where to find first sprite on sheet

    sheet = pygame.image.load(file).convert_alpha() #Load the sheet
    sheet_rect = sheet.get_rect()
    sprites = []
    print sheet_rect.height, sheet_rect.width
    for i in range(0,sheet_rect.height-len_sprt_y,size[1]):#rows
        print "row"
        for i in range(0,sheet_rect.width-len_sprt_x,size[0]):#columns
            print "column"
            sheet.set_clip(pygame.Rect(sprt_rect_x, sprt_rect_y, len_sprt_x, len_sprt_y)) #find sprite you want
            sprite = sheet.subsurface(sheet.get_clip()) #grab the sprite you want
            sprites.append(sprite)
            sprt_rect_x += len_sprt_x

        sprt_rect_y += len_sprt_y
        sprt_rect_x = 0
    print sprites
    return sprites

#VERSION HISTORY

    #1.1 - turned code into useable function

    #2.0 - fully functional sprite sheet loader
```

For reference, this cuts sheets into individual sprites one row at a time from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

The above code posted by aquasheep is brilliant! Although in lines:
`for i in range(0,sheet_rect.height-len_sprt_y,size[1]):#rows`
`for i in range(0,sheet_rect.width-len_sprt_x,size[0]):#columns`

I had to remove `-len_sprt_y` and `-len_sprt_x`  it just would not load the last sprites on the x and y axis. It may vary depending on the sprite sheet x, y size and the actual sprite size too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `set_clip` and `get_clip` as mentioned in the other answers. Just pass a rect, tuple or list to [`Surface.subsurface`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface).

```
# The size of a sprite in this example is 64x64 pixels.
x_coord = 64 * 2  # This would be the third column.
y_coord = 64 * 3  # Fourth row.
width = 64
height = 64

sheet = pygame.image.load('your_sprite_sheet.png').convert_alpha()
single_image = sheet.subsurface((x_coord, y_coord, width, height))
```