# Why am I getting this error: "Invalid rectstyle argument"

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently making a game in python where a ball hits a group of boxes. I have loaded an image of a grass that I wanted the boxes to stand on, the grass image is 600 by 151 pixels. So far I have all the boxes and the ball appearing perfectly however, What is not working currently is when I try to load the image and display it so that the boxes can stand on the grass image instead of falling off.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.color import *
import pymunk as pm
from pymunk import Vec2d
import sys
from random import randint

def to_pygame(p):
    """Small hack to convert pymunk to pygame coordinates"""
    return int(p[0]), int(-p[1]+600)


def add_box(space, size, pos, mass=1.0):
    # pos is a Vec2d object
    points = [(-size, -size), (-size, size), (size,size), (size, -size)]
    moment = pm.moment_for_poly(int(mass), points, (0,0))

    body = pm.Body(mass, moment)
    body.position = pos

    shape = pm.Poly(body, points, (0,0))
    shape.friction = 1
    space.add(body,shape)

    return shape

def draw_box(screen, box):
    ps = box.get_points()
    ps.append(ps[0])
    ps = map(to_pygame, ps)
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, THECOLORS["blue"], ps, 3)


def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Piling boxes")
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    boxes = []
    x = 170
    y = 120
    space = pm.Space()
    space.gravity = (0.0, -100.0)

    ### ground
    body = pm.Body()
    shape = pm.Segment(body, (150,100), (450,100), .0)
    shape.friction = 4.4
    space.add(shape)

    for i in range(5):
        # what is the mass of the box?
        mass = randint(1,3)
        # what size is the box?
        size = randint(10, 35)
        # calculate its position & hold it in a Vec2d

        #x = x + size + 10
        y = y + size
        pos = Vec2d(x,y)

        box = add_box(space, size, pos, mass)
        boxes.append(box)

    while 1:
        clock.tick(15)
        space.step(1/30.0)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit(0)
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit(0)

        screen.fill(THECOLORS["white"])
        test_image = pygame.image.load("grass.png")

        screen.blit(test_image, to_pygame((450,100)), to_pygame((150,100)),3)


        for i in range(len(boxes)):
            draw_box(screen, boxes[i])

        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Post the full traceback, so people don't have to guess where the error happens.

Answer (score 1):

No traceback or error log so it is a bit hard to identify the point of the error, an educated guess would be that you are passing Rectstyle arguments incorrectly somewhere. Please see the documentation for [pygame.Rect](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) on how to pass Rectstyle args correctly.

> ```
> pygame.Rect(left, top, width, height): return Rect
> pygame.Rect((left, top), (width, height)): return Rect
> pygame.Rect(object): return Rect
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
screen.blit(test_image, to_pygame((450,100)), to_pygame((150,100)),3)
```

To blit a surface to to screen, a valid blit is:

```
screen.blit(test_image, (450,100))
```

So you want:

```
screen.blit(test_image, to_pygame((450,100)))
```

Note: The extra args make me think maybe you're trying to use a source rect argument, to use a tileset. But in that case you wouldn't convert world to screen coords twice. Just on destination, not source.

If you do want the spritesheet/tileset, then out [How do you select a sprite image from a sprite sheet in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560446/how-do-you-select-a-sprite-image-from-a-sprite-sheet-in-python) and [Pygame.org/cookbook/SpriteSheet](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/Spritesheet?parent=CookBook)

Answer (score 1):

The third argument in `blit` is the source `area` argument, should be a rectangle, not coordinates:

```
screen.blit(test_image, to_pygame((450,100)), to_pygame((150,100)),3)
```

Perhaps you want this:

```
screen.blit(test_image, to_pygame((450,100)), pygame.Rect((0,0), (150,100)), 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because your call to `screen.blit` is incorrect. See [here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit).

The call could be

```
screen.blit(test_image, to_pygame((450,100)))
```

or perhaps if you wanted to use the area argument,

```
screen.blit(test_image, to_pygame((450,100)), pygame.Rect((0,0), (150,100)), 3)
```

Also, you are loading guess.png in every loop, instead move it out of the while loop, your code will perform better.