# how to implement a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I've been doing an exercise and we need to create a caterpillar with the size attribute from the other function. In this code below I've added a size attribute between 0 and 3.

```
class Caterpillar:

    def __init__(self):
        self.size = random.randrange(0, 3)
        x = random.randrange(50, 950)
        y = random.randrange(50, 950)
        self.xcoord = x
        self.ycoord = y
```

However in this code below when i tried to add the size in this line `pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, red, [x, y, size, 40, 45])` but I got an error.

```
def draw_critter(self, screen):
        x = self.xcoord
        y = self.ycoord
        size = self.size
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, red, [x, y, 40, 45])
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, black, [x + 6, y + 10, 10, 15])
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, black, [x + 24, y + 10, 10, 15])
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (x + 11, y + 1), (x + 9, y - 10), 3)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (x + 25, y + 1), (x + 26, y - 10), 3)
```

I don't understand why I get this error

```
File "D:/UniFiles/Sem/159/critters.py", line 53, in <module>
    critter.draw_critter(screen)
  File "D:\UniFiles\Sem\159\mycritters.py", line 27, in draw_critter
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, red, [x, y, size, 40, 45])
TypeError: Invalid recstyle argument
```

I am not sure if i really get how class works. Could someone please show me an example on how i can implement the draw_critter function to create a whole caterpillar not just the head.

Comment: How is `draw.ellipse` defined? The error message points to the disagreement of what the function was expecting and what you were feeding it.

Comment: The issue isn't in your class implementation, it's in your `pygame.draw.ellipse` usage. Check the [API docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.ellipse) for it - it looks like it's expecting a pygame.Rect object, not a list.

Comment: I don't know what you mean? but I hae these codes above for the main code and another code where it draws the catepillar

Comment: It means you are using the API incorrectly.

Comment: could you please give me an example on how i should do it? Sorry I don't really get it. even if i read it.

Comment: Maybe you should check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/15719567/12505357

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the API docs for ellipse https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.ellipse

`ellipse()` expects:

> ```
> pygame.draw.ellipse()
>     draw an ellipse
>     ellipse(surface, color, rect) -> Rect
>     ellipse(surface, color, rect, width=0) -> Rect
> ```

And what is Rect? It expects this:

> ```
> pygame.Rect
>     pygame object for storing rectangular coordinates
>     Rect(left, top, width, height) -> Rect
>     Rect((left, top), (width, height)) -> Rect
>     Rect(object) -> Rect
> ```

It doesn't mention a size parameter anywhere.

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you want one long ellipses for a caterpillar? Then maybe you can just draw a `size` number of ellipses and space them out a bit.

For example:

```
for s in range(self.size):
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, red, [x + s*10, y, 40, 45])
```

That's just one way, I have no idea how you want it to look.